# How do I enter proxy server details?

Tags: wi-fi, motorola-milestone

My work WiFi routes traffic through a proxy server. Is there a way to enter proxy server settings so that my Android can successfully make web requests?
My previous phone was a WinMo 6.0 and this was easy to do (part of the setup wizard).

I have a Milestone on Android 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [outstanding bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1273) on this, from November 2008, with no sign of a fix.  It's a real PITA, and a really obvious issue.

Comment: Anyone with this problem should visit the bug page above and 'star' this issue so it may get more attention. Unfortunately it's flagged as a 'feature request' whereas I'd consider it as a lack of basic functionality.

Comment: I think the bug is https over proxy rather than http.

Answer (score 2):

You can get to the hidden http proxy settings via the '[Proxy Settings](http://www.appbrain.com/app/http-proxy-settings/org.credil.proxysettings)' app.
[image: 'Proxy Settings app at AppBrain.com]

This should work for http sites and services but Android doesn't currently allow https via proxy!?! (so no Gmail or app downloads).